# How can I see the index entry count and storage when serving from dev_appserver.py?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I hit https://appengine.google.com/datastore/indexes the view the production indexes for my application, the table has columns for "Index Entry Count" and and "Index Storage".  When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/admin/datastore_indexes` to view the local indexes for my application, those columns are missing.  How can I retrieve that information locally?

I have tried clicking "Generate Datastore stats" on the Datastore Stats page, as well as directly calling `db.get_indexes()`.

I am trying to estimate / verify the size of a new index I would like to create.

Answer (score 0):

If I click on Generate Datastore Stats I'm getting back a message that looks like this:

> Scanned 123 entities of total 42729 bytes, 2208 index entries of total 201760 bytes and 8 composite index entries of total 1080 bytes. Inserted 120 new records.

Is that what you need to know?

Also if you upgrade to the latest version you will have a better dev console which by default is being served on: `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Yes, I get a similar message, but this sums everything together.  I need a breakdown for each individual index.

Comment: @MattFaus I'm afraid that this is what you can get from the dev server.. You could deploy something on an experimental app and make your calculations there without disturbing the real application..! You can always vacuum the indexes so I don't think that it is a big issue to try it on a real application as well..